# Using curly brackets({}) for REGEX in drupal db_query

Tags: drupal

I have a where clause in my query like this "WHERE sth REGEXP '[0-9]{5,10}'"

when I run this query in phpmyadmin it returns all matched records but in drupal it has no result.I think it's because drupal assumes everything like "{sth}" as a table.

how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Whilst Drupal does use braces to delimit table names, I wouldn't expect it to do this inside strings.

Comment: OK, [the source](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/6/source) seems to imply that it does. How lame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your theory is [correct](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_query/6#comment-7444).

Curly brackets used as repetition quantifier in regexes are removed as any other curly bracket. Pass the regex as an argument to db_query() instead like this:

```
db_query('SELECT name from {users} WHERE std RLIKE "%s"', '[0-9]{5,10}');
```

(I've had to guess at the rest of your query.)